Chat appears down
It appears Chat is down:



Seems up again, if anybody else experienced chat issues please comment below.

Works for me.  Is it still broken for anyone else?

Note that there seems to be some hidden characters behind the URL in the picture. Not sure what it says, but it could have something to do with the error.

Chat works for me too

The URL in the screenshot is wrong. There is no specific chat instance for crypto SE. There is only one on chat.stackexchange.com (and one for SO). Going to https://chat.crypto.stackexchange.com does indeed reproduce the shown behavior.

@SEJPM That looks like an answer potato

@EllaRose I'm on my phone right now and as a matter of principle I don't write answers from my phone. If you want to, you can of course answer with the new knowledge or I'll do it myself in ~2-3h.

I guess we should ask jww if the usual link ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/784/the-side-channel ) also works for them before declaring "problem solved". Was any of this helpful @jww ? Or is there still an issue?

From the screenshot, we can see that chat.crypto.stackexchange.com was requested and indeed, requesting this address reproducibly gives the shown error (it also gives a certificate domain missmatch error for me). Whether this a bug or not, I don't know (also I'm mildly surprised that this DNS record even exists).
Now, what you are actually looking for is chat.stackexchange.com as the server hosting does so for all rooms for all stackexchange sites (excluding stackoverflow). If the problem persists with the correct URL, please comment, so we can escalate the issue if neccessary.
As this issue also affects other site's subdomains I have posted it to Meta.SE for further tracking and handling, though don't expect a "fix" soon as this is just a site that couldn't be generated and doesn't impact anything else.

"please comment, so we can escalate the issue if necessary..." - Thanks. I think you should escalate an application crash. It is unexpected, and I doubt the management designed the site to crash. I'd be curious to learn, why do the moderators here feel an application crash is OK, and why do they need to be told to do something about it? Shouldn't this post trigger the triage without someone spoon feeding advice like, "your application is crashing, you should fix  it".

@jww For context on why I asked first: It's not a "crash" in my understanding but simply a webserver that can't process a URL and gives up, there's likely 0 impact on anything else the server does. Also the address in question isn't even reachable / visible from the UI and you have to manually type it to see the page not working. (For reference: The "safe" way to get to chat is to expand the list of sites in the UI in the top right corner and clicking "chat" to the right of the current site name)

@jww I've removed my previous comment as I suppose your comment has come from frustration. But please note that mods are not site maintainers, and that you can mail the SE team yourself. This is also unlikely to be a crypto specific issue (if it is one). The same thing happens for e.g. chat.security.stackexchange.com, to name just one example.
